# Error AADSTS65001 while getting access token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have registered an application in Azure AD. I am trying to get an access token for Azure SQL Database.

I am sending the request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant/oauth2/v2.0/token

But I am getting the below error as a response.

```
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
```

Is there something wrong with the authentication request? Or am I missing any permissions?
If it is how to set those permissions?
I don't know what's going wrong.

Can anyone help me out to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially please check with your admin to check if he/her had been consented to the request .

Please make sure to give basic permissions required to access the app and grant consent for them in portal . Or make sure the admin has consented .

[image]

Also see [aadsts65001](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-when/m-p/832187) and check if scope parameter added in the request for V2 endpoint.

See if you need to have [Directory Readers role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-directory-readers-role#:%7E:text=The%20Directory%20Readers%20role%20can%20be%20used%20as,to%20create%20Azure%20AD%20users%20in%20Azure%20SQL) to access azure sql database(if not ask the admin to provide the same)  or also select Directory.Read.All permissions from API permissions as above. or even we can set from roles and administrator section.

Answer (score 1):

Privileged permissions (delegated or application type) require Admin Consent. If you know the directory id and application (client) id, you can send the consent link to an admin (with Global Admin role) who can grant the consent-
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/[your-azure-ad-directory-id]/adminconsent?client_id=[your-client-id]](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Byour-azure-ad-directory-id%5D/adminconsent?client_id=%5Byour-client-id%5D)

Just replace the directory id and client id!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be 100% relevant, but I encountered the same problem while using an application to obtain an updated `access_token` from a `refresh_token` for an external user that did not belong to the tenant domain.  After wasting a great deal of time trying to figure work out consents and permission, I realised that I was calling the wrong end point.

So using the

```
 `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
```

gave me the AADSTS65001 error.   I finally realised that (for users that do not belong to the tenant associated with the application) I needed to use the

```
 `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
```

end point.

Complete code for those interested:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $response = $client->post($url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
        ],
    ]);
   return  json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
```